# Hessian of a smooth homogeneous polynomial of degree $d \ge 3$ is homogeneous of degree $3(d-2)$?

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, projective-space

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, let $f(X,Y,Z) \in k[X,Y,Z]$ be a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d \ge 3$ such that $\Big(\dfrac {\partial f}{\partial X} (p) ,\dfrac {\partial f}{\partial Y} (p) , \dfrac {\partial f}{\partial Z} (p) \Big)\ne (0,0,0), \forall 0\ne p \in k^3$ i.e. the projective curve given by $f$ is smooth. Consider the determinant of the Hessian matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) of $f$, denote it by $H(f)$ . Then is it true that $H(f)$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $3(d-2)$ ?

Due to my conditions, it s easy to see that $f$ is irreducible (by Bezout's Theorem) and that if we have a projective change of coordinates given by $A \in Gl(3,k)$ , then $H(f)(X,Y,Z)=\det(A)^2 H(g)((X, Y,Z)A^t)$, where $g(X,Y,Z)=f((X,Y,Z))(A^{-1})^t)$; so the degree of the Hessian doesn't change with a projective change of co-ordinates. I'm unable to deduce anything else.

Please help.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. The entries of the Hessian are second derivatives  and so all are homogeneous of degree $d-2$. So, the determinant is homogeneous of degree $3(d-2)$.

Comment: @Mohan: What you say is not really always true ... take for example $f=Y^3-XZ^2$, then $f_{XX}=0$

Comment: Zero polynomial is considered of any degree you wish.